# Circumvent random number in ID

Tags: jquery

I got this line in my script, which check the items class:

```
$('#post').attr('class');
```

Is there a chance, to read it like:

```
$('#post*').attr('class');
```

So if the ID will be fe. `post405` it will still read this?
I've checked it and it won't work with `*` , so so there any other way to read items this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('[id^=post]').attr('class');
```

You're looking for the [`[attribute^=*]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're doing a class based search on the id.  This is really not the recommended way to do this.  The more "proper" way would be to add a "post" class to your elements and look for

```
$('.post')
```

of course, if you're looking for the class attribute, there's a lot you can do with that too... using the `attr()` function for that is probably not what you want.

Comment: Yeah, but inside of the script I'm checking if it has class `pixelize` if not then it'll add it, so... I can not use it I think :/

Comment: you can't do `$('.post').hasClass('pixelize')` or something along those lines?

Comment: yeah I think what you want is to add a "post" class to the posts and then do something like `$('.post').addClass('pixelize');`

Comment: @Jeremy: Simpler: `$('.post.pixelize')...` (only selects elements with both class names applied)

Comment: @BradChristie (with the understanding that it already has the "pixelize" class... I think OP wanted to make sure it was there) I couldn't remember if that was legal selector syntax.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery already provides a "starts with" selector for this purpose.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$('[id^="post"]').attr('class');
```